# Iterate though dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary which includes nested dictionaries that look similar to this:

```
mydict = {'1': {'agent': 'xxxxxx', 'manager': 'aaaaaa'}, '2': {'agent': '22222', 'manager': 'bbbbb'}, '3': {'agent': 'zxzx', 'manager': 'aqaq'}}
```

I need to iterate through the dictionary, pulling out the value for agent, and the value for manager, but I'm not having much success in trying. Here's what I have now:

```
for i in mydict:
    agent = i['agent']
    manager = i['manager']

(here is where I do stuff with
    those variables)
```

This seems to work only for the first entry in the dictionary, and then the loop exits.

Comment: `agent` and `manager` are *overwritten* each iteration of the loop

Comment: replace the `i` inside the `for` loop with `mydict[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the most readable way to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    agent = v['agent']
    manager = v['manager']
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks for the simple reply. I see where I was wrong, and I was able to fix my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you loop mydict.items() you will recibe key, value pairs:

```
for num, data in mydict.items():
    print(data["agent"])
    print(data["manager"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the agents and managers you may want them in a list:

```
mydict = {'1': {'agent': 'xxxxxx', 'manager': 'aaaaaa'}, '2': {'agent': '22222', 'manager': 'bbbbb'}, '3': {'agent': 'zxzx', 'manager': 'aqaq'}}


am = [(i['agent'], i['manager']) for i in mydict.values()]

print(am)
```

Output:

```
[('xxxxxx', 'aaaaaa'), ('22222', 'bbbbb'), ('zxzx', 'aqaq')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of your current `for` loop is assigning a different `"agent"` and `"manager"` to the `agent` and `manager` variables. Thus, at the end of the iteration, `agent` and `manager` will store the last `"agent"` and `"manager"` strings. To create list of the agent and managers in a for loop, you can use a generator:

```
def get_agents_managers(d):
  for _, b in d.items():
    yield [b['agent'], b['manager']]

s = {'1': {'agent': 'xxxxxx', 'manager': 'aaaaaa'}, '2': {'agent': '22222', 'manager': 'bbbbb'}, '3': {'agent': 'zxzx', 'manager': 'aqaq'}}
print(list(get_agents_managers(s)))
```

Output:

```
[['xxxxxx', 'aaaaaa'], ['zxzx', 'aqaq'], ['22222', 'bbbbb']]
```